# Can't find 'Definitely lost memory' in my code

Tags: c, heap-memory, valgrind

I'm trying to create some programs in order to be correctly prepared for the test, that will be really soon. 
But actually, after some days of research on these codes, I can't find where the memory leaks, that are reported by valgrind, actually are.

I tried by freeing almost every pointer, internal and external. I tried freeing some unnecessary pointers, without any result.

This is the struct:

```
typedef struct cop {
   int primo;
   int secondo;
   struct cop *next; 
 } coppia
```

These are the functions:

```
coppia *crea_coppia(int x, int y)
{
    coppia *el=malloc(sizeof(coppia));
    el->primo=x;
    el->secondo=y;
    el->next=NULL;
    return el;
}

coppia *crea_coppia_bin(FILE *f)
{
    int buf[2];

    int e = fread(buf,sizeof(int),2,f);

    if(e!=2) return NULL;

    coppia *el = crea_coppia(buf[0],buf[1]);

    if(el==NULL) return NULL;

    return el;
}

coppia *crea_lista(char *nomefile)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(nomefile,"rb");
    coppia *lis=NULL;
    coppia *el=NULL;
    while(true)
    {
        el=crea_coppia_bin(f);
        if(el==NULL)
            break;
        lis=inserisci_coppia(lis,el);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return lis;
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
==434== HEAP SUMMARY:
==434==     in use at exit: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==434==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 8 frees, 8,840 bytes allocated
==434==
==434== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==434==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==434==    by 0x10896D: crea_coppia (provaesame.c:18)
==434==    by 0x1089D1: crea_coppia_bin (provaesame.c:53)
==434==    by 0x108A12: crea_lista (provaesame.c:77)
==434==    by 0x108B6D: main (provaesamemain.c:21)
==434==
==434== LEAK SUMMARY:
==434==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==434==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==434==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==434==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==434==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==434==
==434== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==434== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

This is the function that inserts the element into the list:

```
coppia *inserisci_coppia(coppia *lis, coppia *el)
{
    if(lis==NULL)
    {
        lis=el;
        return lis;
    }
    else
    {
        el->next=lis;
        lis=el;
        return lis;
    }
}
```

This is the freeing function:

```
void distruggi_lista_coppie(coppia *lis)
{
    while(lis!=NULL)
    {
        coppia *prossimo=lis->next;
        jr_free(lis);
        lis=prossimo;
    }
}
```

Nevermind, I found the solution, there was a function in where I had to find the maximum couple of the entire list, and I had to print that alone. So I was setting to NULL the pointer of the next element, this maximum element was the second last, so the last element was lost.

Comment: I don't see a single call to `free()` in the code you included in the question. So it's clear why you have memory leaks. If you have another version with calls to `free()` which still produces errors under Valgrind, you should post it (as a [mre], not an excerpt) along with the textual errors produced.

Comment: `el=malloc(sizeof(coppia));` allocates memory. But there is no place where you free it.

Comment: I have a freeing function, frees all the memory, but still there's something that delete the pointer to the last element of the list.

Comment: Instead of all the empty lines, you could have showed us your`main()` driver function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add in my own `jr_malloc` and `jr_free` and just see what's being called. These functions in turn would call `malloc` and `free`.

```
void *jr_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p = malloc(size);
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc: %d %p\n", size, p);
    return p;
}

void jr_free(void *p)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "free: %p\n", p);
    free(p);
}
```

You might be able to compare and see which `p` is not being freed.

Comment: I tried using those functions, the result is that I cannot free the last block allocated with malloc.

Comment: This suggests that your code is trying to free the last one twice, so maybe it's skipping the first one? Do you see any `p` in `malloc` not showing up in `free`?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely lost memory is memory which has not been freed, and which cannot be freed because the program no longer has a pointer to the memory. (See the [Valgrind FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost) for a more complete list of possible types of memory leaks.)

In case that's unclear, here's a simple example:

```
char* buffer;
while (1) {
  buffer = malloc(BUF_LEN);
  if (fgets(buffer, BUF_LEN, stdin) == NULL) break;
  fprintf(stderr, "Read: %s", buffer);
  // process(buffer);
}
```

The second time through the loop the only pointer to the memory allocated is lost, because it wasn't freed and the only pointer to it was overwritten. Since the program no longer has a pointer to the first allocated `buffer`, it cannot `free()` it later.

In a real implementation, `process` might do something which preserves the pointer (insert it into a linked list, for example), or it might even `free()` the buffer, although some would consider that bad design. If it saves the pointer, then the memory is not yet definitively lost, but the program must at some point run through the repository of stored pointers and free each of them.